# Integrate velodyne and INS data

Tags: mapping, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am working on project where I need to combine LIDAR scans and INS data together. I am using velodyne 32e model that i want to mount on UAV so INS data is important for accuracy. I can collect the LIDAR data and INS data in rosbag format that i want to convert into las format with accurate positioning. So that i can view data in ArcGIS.

I am able to convert lidar data to las format but unable to combine Position INS data with it

Is there any suggestion how can i do this???
thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253482/integrate-velodyne-and-ins-data/) by [Nikka](https://answers.ros.org/users/28163/nikka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PG_GrantDare](https://answers.ros.org/users/38516/pg_grantdare/) on 2019-07-23**:
Hi, I am not very experienced in GIS applications. How did you convert PC2 data to .las? I have not found resources to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The general ROS answer is to provide the appropriate coordinate frame transforms (using [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) or [tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2)). To do that, you'll probably need to feed your INU data into some form of 3D localization package.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nikka](https://answers.ros.org/users/28163/nikka/) on 2017-02-02**:
Thank you for instant reply,
I am new to ros so plz can you suggest me any tutorial that will help me with this?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-02-04**:
http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials